# JQuery mouseleave and then mouseover within a fadeOut duration set in mouseleave

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events

I can't seem to find a solution for this issue I am having. What's occurring is that when I trigger mouseleave and then try to trigger mouseover within the duration set of mouseleave to fadeOut(), mouseover doesn't trigger. Is there a way to fix this or should i use something the jquery animate function?

```
$("#homepage-slider").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".direction-next").fadeTo(500, .7);
        $(".direction-previous").fadeTo(500, .7);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".direction-next").fadeOut(500);
        $(".direction-previous").fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you'll need to `stop` the animation, `clear the queue` and then `jump to the end`.

How might you do that? By utilizing jQuery's `.stop(true,true)`.

```
$("#homepage-slider").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".direction-next").stop(true, true).fadeTo(500, .7);
        $(".direction-previous").stop(true, true).fadeTo(500, .7);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".direction-next").fadeOut(500);
        $(".direction-previous").fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

[obligatory jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2bwu8p1/)